# I need to add dependency in my package.json and load module , after taking user input while running npm install {some dependency}

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json

I need to add a dependency in my package.json and load module, by taking user input in command prompt while running npm install  {some dependency}.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible or not. But, it sure sounds like very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [Yeoman Generator](https://yeoman.io/authoring/) to do it.